# subString combined with the practices of the for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, substring

I get a long list of strings from the server

```
  AS=  String1 ~ String2 ~ String3 ~
```

Can be determined.
"~"Represents the end of each data.
I know that the word limit for each String of up to 22
But I do not know his actual length.

So I use this code to determine the value of each String

```
//////////////////////////Use of substring Get every character
String T1=AS.substring(0,1);
String T2=AS.substring(1,2);
             .              
             .              
             .              
String T22=AS.substring(21,22);

 if (T2.equals("~")) {
    DATA=T1;
}


 if (T3.equals("~")) {
    DATA=T1+T2;
}
//Confirm T3 "~" Get DATA = T2 + T1


String LG=LG+DATA.length()+1;
//The second document must be added to the number of words in the document "~"
String TT1=AS.substring(0+LG,1+LG);
```

Determine string of 100
Repeat 100 times
I have manufactured more than 8,000 lines of code
There is no easier way to reach my request?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? Your code looks to be extremely inefficient and not very scaleable.

Comment: Please avoid self-deprecation here. You are not stupid (unless proven otherwise). Please explain exactly what it is that you're trying to do. What is your input? what is your expected output?

Comment: Yes, it's not  your job to insult yourself. That's *our* job. But seriously, please take a little time to describe the problem in greater detail. This will greatly help our analysis.

Comment: Give me some time I need to re-edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little bit to help you out.

```
String[] TKG = new String[GUY.length];

for (int i = 0; i < GUY.length - 1; i++)
{
  TKG[i] = GUY.substring(i, i+1);
}
```

and then

```
StringBuilder DETA5 = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < TKG.length; i++)
{
  if (TKG[i].equals("~"))
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
      DETA5.append(TKG[x]);
    }
  }
}

int D = D + DETA5.length();

String[] TKC = new String[6];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  TKC[i] = GUY.substring(i+D1, i + 1 + D1);
}

StringBuilder DETA_1_1 = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < TKC.length; i++)
{
  if (TKC[i].equals("~"))
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
      DETA_1_1.append(TKC[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks almost as if a simple `String#split(...)` will do the trick for you. Have you tried something along the lines of

```
String[] tokens = guy.split("~");
```

Perhaps after a little cleaning up of the edge Strings, you'll have what you want.